# what is the relationship between the two standard errors

Tags: regression, distributions, variance

I have two variables $X$ and $Y$.

Consider that there is one sample with 1000 observations, we can get the standard error of coefficient by this equation:
$se(\hat\beta) = \sqrt{\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}}$.

Then consider that we have 100 samples, each sample has 1000 observations. By running 100 regressions, we can get 100 $\hat\beta$. Then, we can compute the standard error of the mean:
$SEM=\sum(\hat\beta-\bar{\beta})^2/100$.

So what is the relationship between the two standard errors?

Comment: What is the relationship among the various design matrices $X$ for each of the 100 samples?

Comment: Hi, $X$ is generated from normal distribution. And I replicated it 100 times. So each of the sample follows the same distribution.